# What part of speech is "why" in the following example?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentence "Why is this here?", is "why" an adverb? What part of speech is "why?" I think it modifies the verb "is", so I think it is an adverb.

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: From [Yahoo Answers:](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100616002448AArCkum) *It is an adverb. That is, words like Why, what, when, how, etc describe how some activity (verb) was done; hence they are called Ad-verbs!*

Comment: Yes, it's an adverb here, functioning as an adjunct (modifier) in clause structure. It questions cause (reason or purpose). and would typically elicit an answer like "Because it catches the drips".

Comment: Sometimes, when "Why?" is by itself, it dreams of being an interjection. But that doesn't lessen its adverbiness.

Comment: @Spencer -- Ahem...  That's "adverbialness".

Comment: @HotLicks Not nearly precious enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Should we not call them *interrogative adverbs* to match with the *interrogative pronoun* - "who"?

Comment: @WS2: I think John Lawler just calls them **wh-words**. But I don't think he's a big fan of "parts of speech" categorisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's an adverb. And in your case, it does modify the verb *is*. When used as an adverb, *why* has the meaning of for what reason or purpose. Semantically, it fits your example perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Point to consider: Parts of Speech in English are fluid and depend upon context and function in real language situations. "Why" is most often used as an Object of a verb, as in "She wondered WHY," (what she wondered), not as the verb's adverb, as in "Why did she wonder?"

But, just to mess things up a little more, consider this: "why" can inarguably replace a noun, a noun phrase, clause or more, so it can also therefore be used as a pronoun, ("She knew [what did she know?] -she knew why."]

What's worse for those old fossilized grammar school pedants is that "Why" can even be considered a relative pronoun, (perish the thought!). Quirk & Greenbaum: *A University Grammar of English* chapter 13, section 7 notes that 3 of those nasty "wh" pronouns can function as relative pros. For example, in the sentence, "The man walked to the place 'where' the shooting occurred," Where acts as a relative answering 'which' "place" – WHERE the shooting occurred"!

Answer (score -2):

' why are you here ' - it reflects an exclamatory sense. Hence, 'why' should be an interjection.

Comment: 'Why! They are here already!' shows the exclamatory usage, interchangeable with 'Oh my!' This is a totally different usage.