# Why the sad face?

Tags: parts-of-speech

A previous question ([What part of speech is 'why' ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430720/what-part-of-speech-is-why-in-the-following-example)) asked what function 'why' was playing when it is used with a verb.

But 'why' can be used without a verb.

> Why the sad face ?

So what is it doing when it is all on its own ?

Comment: "*Why do you have the sad face?*" is understood.  The verb is missing because the phrase can easily be understood without it.  This is an ellipsis - very common in idiomatic, spoken English.

Comment: So the missing words are an ellipsis, but what part of speech is the 'why' ?

Comment: Looks like 'why' is an *interrogative adverb*  - https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/interrogative-adverbs/ - if that helps at all

Comment: But adverbs modify verbs. And there is no verb . . . . . .